# Grey piece to the right of background

Tags: html, css, web

to the right of background keep grey piece:http://www.bestmonsterhigh.ru/
How I can remove this grey ugly piece?

Comment: Please post a relevant JSfiddle or something similar. We are not going to debug your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `width:350px` to `.login-block`

Comment: Thanks! I was wery inattentive((